# Vulkan pipeline(s) sometimes do not complete in every frame

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, gpu, vulkan

Good afternoon,

I'm using Vulkan to establish a pipeline in Android for edge detection.
This had to be done due to Google recommendation of migrating from (deprecated) Renderscript to Vulkan.

This has been working fine in all devices that i could get my hands on until I came across a smartphone ([Galaxy A23 5G](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a23_5g-11736.php)) that is showing a weird behaviour. This is making me think the pipeline and the very verbose Vulkan setup code might not be completely right and stable for production...

The behaviour is typical of the shaders not completing somehow. The most curious fact is that it seems it stops "working" always in the same row of the image (320 on a VGA image). Please see images attached that represent a good and bad working case on this particular device. The application is working at VGA resolution using Camera1.

An important note to make is that this only happens if i pass a ByteBuffer holding the camera data to the pipeline. If i use the pipeline loading from a Bitmap image it seems it never fails...

**Good case**

[image]

**Bad case**

[image]

**Pipeline Code**

```
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include "vulkan_operations.h"
#include "buffer.h"

namespace Vulkan {

    namespace {

        uint32_t ceilOfDiv(uint32_t lhs, uint32_t rhs) {
            return (lhs + rhs - 1) / rhs;
        }

        bool beginOneTimeCommandBuffer(VkCommandBuffer cmd) {
            VkCommandBufferBeginInfo commandBufferBeginInfo = {};
            commandBufferBeginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
            commandBufferBeginInfo.pNext = nullptr;
            commandBufferBeginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
            commandBufferBeginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr;

            vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmd, &commandBufferBeginInfo);
            return true;
        }

        bool endAndSubmitCommandBuffer(VkCommandBuffer cmd, VkQueue queue) {
            // End command buffer recording
            vkEndCommandBuffer(cmd);

            // Submit queue
            VkSubmitInfo submitDesc = {};
            submitDesc.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
            submitDesc.waitSemaphoreCount = 0;
            submitDesc.pWaitSemaphores = nullptr;
            submitDesc.pWaitDstStageMask = nullptr;
            submitDesc.commandBufferCount = 1;
            submitDesc.pCommandBuffers = &cmd;
            submitDesc.signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
            submitDesc.pSignalSemaphores = nullptr;
            vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitDesc, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
            vkQueueWaitIdle(queue);
            return true;
        }
    }  // namespace

    void VulkanOperations::initVulkan(AAssetManager* manager) {
        mContext = VulkanContext::create(true);
        createCommandBuffer();
        createPipeline(manager);
    }

    /**
     * Preallocate all the buffers/images that will be used during Canny.
     * <p>
     * This method must be called before canny(uint8_t* byteBuffer, uint32_t thres_l, uint32_t thres_h).
     * @param width the width of the input image
     * @param height the height of the input image
     * @param edgeMap the edge map float array that will be populated during canny(uint8_t*, uint32_t, uint32_t)
     * @param gx the X gradient float array that will be populated during canny(uint8_t*, uint32_t, uint32_t)
     * @param gy the Y gradient float array that will be populated during canny(uint8_t*, uint32_t, uint32_t)
     */
    void VulkanOperations::preallocate(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, int32_t* edgeMap, float* gxArray, float* gyArray) {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
        this->edgeMap = edgeMap;
        this->gxArray = gxArray;
        this->gyArray = gyArray;

        auto image_size = width * height;
        this->ex = new int32_t[image_size];
        this->ey = new int32_t[image_size];
        this->outputNmsArray = new uint32_t[image_size];

        // TODO: could experiment with flags here
        mStagingBuffer = Buffer::create(mContext.get(), image_size,
                                        VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);

        // Input image (lives in the GPU - DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)
        mInputImage = Image::create(mContext.get(), width, height,
                                    VK_FORMAT_R8_UINT, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
                                    VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
                                    VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        // Temp output smooth image (lives in the GPU - DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)
        mTempImage = Image::create(mContext.get(), width, height,
                                   VK_FORMAT_R8_UINT, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
                                   VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
                                   VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        // Smooth output image (lives in the GPU - DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)
        mOutputSmoothImage = Image::create(mContext.get(), width, height,
                                           VK_FORMAT_R8_UINT, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
                                           VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
                                           VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        // Output sobel gx image (lives in the GPU - DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)
        mOutputGxImage = Image::create(mContext.get(), width, height,
                                       VK_FORMAT_R32_SFLOAT, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
                                       VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT,
                                       VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        // Output sobel gy image (lives in the GPU - DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)
        mOutputGyImage = Image::create(mContext.get(), width, height,
                                       VK_FORMAT_R32_SFLOAT, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
                                       VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT,
                                       VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        // Output [magnitude, direction], 2 channel image (lives in the GPU - DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)
        mOutputSobelImage = Image::create(mContext.get(), width, height,
                                          VK_FORMAT_R32G32_UINT, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
                                          VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
                                          VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
        // Output nms (lives in the GPU - DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT)
        mOutputNmsImage = Image::create(mContext.get(), width, height,
                                        VK_FORMAT_R32_SINT, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
                                        VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
                                        VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        // Result buffer for nms image copy (CACHED, which requires vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges after copying back to ensure coherence)
        mResultBuffer = Buffer::create(mContext.get(), image_size * 4,
                                       VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT);

        // X Gradients (CACHED, which requires vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges after copying back to ensure coherence)
        mGxBuffer = Buffer::create(mContext.get(), image_size * 4,
                                   VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT);

        // Y Gradients (CACHED, which requires vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges after copying back to ensure coherence)
        mGyBuffer = Buffer::create(mContext.get(), image_size * 4,
                                   VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT);
    }

    /**
     * Main Canny method.
     * <p>
     * This method must be called after preallocate(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, int32_t* edgeMap, float* gx, float* gy).
     * @param byteBuffer the buffer containing the input data
     * @param thres_l the lower threshold
     * @param thres_h the higher threshold
     * @return nEdges
     */
    uint32_t VulkanOperations::canny(uint8_t* byteBuffer, uint32_t thres_l, uint32_t thres_h) {

        // Update thresholds that'll be used in sobel shader
        mCannyThresholds.thresholds[0] = thres_l;
        mCannyThresholds.thresholds[1] = thres_h;

        // Copy the ByteBuffer to Vulkan buffer
        void* dataIn;
        vkMapMemory(mContext->device(), mStagingBuffer->getBufferMemory(), 0, mStagingBuffer->getSize(), 0, &dataIn);
        memcpy(dataIn, byteBuffer, (size_t)mStagingBuffer->getSize());
        vkUnmapMemory(mContext->device(), mStagingBuffer->getBufferMemory());

        // Start one-time command buffer
        beginOneTimeCommandBuffer(mCommandBuffer);

        // Record the copy of the VkBuffer to a VkImage
        mInputImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, true);
        mStagingBuffer->recordCopyBufferToImage(mCommandBuffer, mInputImage->getImageHandle(), width, height);
        mInputImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, true);

        // Record the first pipeline (shader_5x1) to the command buffer
        mTempImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, false);
        mBlurHorizontalPipeline->recordComputeCommands(mCommandBuffer, &height, *mInputImage, *mTempImage);
        mTempImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, true);

        // Record the second pipeline (shader_1x5) to the command buffer
        mOutputSmoothImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, false);
        mBlurVerticalPipeline->recordComputeCommands(mCommandBuffer, &width, *mTempImage, *mOutputSmoothImage);
        mOutputSmoothImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, true);

        // Record the third pipeline (shader_sobel) to the command buffer (with 3 'output' images)
        mOutputSobelImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, false);
        mOutputGxImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, false);
        mOutputGyImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, false);
        mSobelPipeline->recordComputeCommands(mCommandBuffer, &mCannyThresholds,
                                              *mOutputSmoothImage, *mOutputSobelImage,
                                              *mOutputGxImage, *mOutputGyImage);

        // Record the layout transition for all output images (gx/gy will be copied out directly)
        mOutputSobelImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, true);
        mOutputGxImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, true);
        mOutputGyImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, true);

        // Record the last pipeline (shader_nms) to the command buffer
        mOutputNmsImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, false);
        mNmsPipeline->recordComputeCommands(mCommandBuffer, nullptr, *mOutputSobelImage, *mOutputNmsImage);
        mOutputNmsImage->recordLayoutTransitionBarrier(mCommandBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, true);

        // Record the copy of mOutputNmsImage data out to VkBuffer
        mOutputNmsImage->recordCopyImageToBuffer(mCommandBuffer, *mResultBuffer);

        // Record the copy of mOutputGxImage data out to VkBuffer
        mOutputGxImage->recordCopyImageToBuffer(mCommandBuffer, *mGxBuffer);

        // Record the copy of mOutputGyImage data out to VkBuffer
        mOutputGyImage->recordCopyImageToBuffer(mCommandBuffer, *mGyBuffer);

        // End and submit command buffer (all recorded commands will be executed now)
        endAndSubmitCommandBuffer(mCommandBuffer, mContext->queue());

        auto size = mResultBuffer->getSize();

        // Copy from VkBuffers to c++ arrays
        mResultBuffer->copyBufferToArray(outputNmsArray, size);
        mGxBuffer->copyBufferToArray(gxArray, size);
        mGyBuffer->copyBufferToArray(gyArray, size);

        mEdgeCount = 0;
        int32_t i = 0, y, x, j;
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                auto index = y * width + x;
                if (outputNmsArray[index] >= thres_h * thres_h) {
                    edgeMap[index] = 1;
                    ex[mEdgeCount] = x;
                    ey[mEdgeCount] = y;
                    mEdgeCount++;
                } else {
                    edgeMap[index] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        while (i < mEdgeCount) {
            x = ex[i];
            y = ey[i];
            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                auto index = (y + mOy[j]) * width + x + mOx[j];
                if (edgeMap[index] == 0) {
                    if (outputNmsArray[index] >= thres_l * thres_l) {
                        edgeMap[index] = 1;
                        ex[mEdgeCount] = x + mOx[j];
                        ey[mEdgeCount] = y + mOy[j];
                        mEdgeCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        return mEdgeCount;
    }

    /**
     * Flushes all the variables involved in canny.
     * <p>
     * This method checks first whether each variable was created/instantiated before
     * calling the corresponding Vulkan flushing method. This is to ensure that even a
     * "half-instantiated" Vulkan context can be flushed Exception-free.
     */
    void VulkanOperations::flush() {
        if (mInputImage != nullptr) mInputImage->destroy();
        if (mOutputSmoothImage != nullptr) mOutputSmoothImage->destroy();

        if (mTempImage != nullptr) mTempImage->destroy();
        if (mOutputGxImage != nullptr) mOutputGxImage->destroy();
        if (mOutputGyImage != nullptr) mOutputGyImage->destroy();
        if (mOutputSobelImage != nullptr) mOutputSobelImage->destroy();
        if (mOutputNmsImage != nullptr) mOutputNmsImage->destroy();
        if (mStagingBuffer != nullptr) mStagingBuffer->destroy();
        if (mResultBuffer != nullptr) mResultBuffer->destroy();
        if (mGxBuffer != nullptr) mGxBuffer->destroy();
        if (mGyBuffer != nullptr) mGyBuffer->destroy();

        if (mBlurHorizontalPipeline != nullptr) mBlurHorizontalPipeline->destroy();
        if (mBlurVerticalPipeline != nullptr) mBlurVerticalPipeline->destroy();
        if (mSobelPipeline != nullptr) mSobelPipeline->destroy();
        if (mNmsPipeline != nullptr) mNmsPipeline->destroy();

        if (mContext != nullptr) {
            vkFreeCommandBuffers(mContext->device(), mContext->commandPool(), 1, &mCommandBuffer);
            mContext->destroy();
        }
        delete[] outputNmsArray;
        delete[] ex;
        delete[] ey;
    }

    /**
     * Creates all the necessary Pipeline objects for canny.
     * @param manager Asset manager to read the shader files
     */
    void VulkanOperations::createPipeline(AAssetManager* manager) {
        mBlurHorizontalPipeline = Pipeline::create(mContext.get(), manager, "shaders/shader_5x1.comp.spv", sizeof(uint32_t));
        mBlurVerticalPipeline = Pipeline::create(mContext.get(), manager, "shaders/shader_1x5.comp.spv", sizeof(uint32_t));
        mSobelPipeline = Pipeline::create(mContext.get(), manager, "shaders/shader_sobel.comp.spv", sizeof(uint32_t)*2, true);
        mNmsPipeline = Pipeline::create(mContext.get(), manager, "shaders/shader_nms.comp.spv", sizeof(uint32_t));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a command buffer, on which all the canny-related commands are recorded.
     * <p>
     * Note that this implementation of canny only uses one command buffer,
     * containing all the commands to be processed one after the other.
     * @see canny(uint8_t* byteBuffer, uint32_t thres_l, uint32_t thres_h)
     */
    void VulkanOperations::createCommandBuffer() {
        VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo{};
        allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
        allocInfo.commandPool = mContext->commandPool();
        allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
        allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

        if (vkAllocateCommandBuffers(mContext->device(), &allocInfo, &mCommandBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate command buffers!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Shaders Code**

```
#version 450 core
#pragma shader_stage(compute)

layout (local_size_x_id = 0, local_size_y_id = 1) in;

layout (binding=0) uniform usampler2D inputImage;
layout (binding=1, r8ui) uniform writeonly uimage2D outputImage;

layout (push_constant, std140) uniform PushConstant {
    uint width;
} constant;

const uint kernel[5] = uint[5](56,250,412,250,56);

void main()
{
    int width = int(constant.width);
    ivec2 coord = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x,gl_GlobalInvocationID.y);
    uvec4 outPixel = uvec4(0,0,0,255);
    uint sum=0;
    for(int dc=0;dc<5;dc++){
        int xc=coord.x+dc-2;
        if(xc<0){
            xc=0;
        }
        if(xc>=width){
            xc=width-1;
        }
        vec2 c = vec2(xc,gl_GlobalInvocationID.y);
        sum+=texture(inputImage,c).r*kernel[dc];
    }
    outPixel.r = sum>>10;
    imageStore(outputImage,coord,outPixel);
}
```

---

```
#version 450 core
#pragma shader_stage(compute)

layout (local_size_x_id = 0, local_size_y_id = 1) in;

layout (binding=0) uniform usampler2D inputImage;
layout (binding=1, r8ui) uniform writeonly uimage2D outputImage;

layout (push_constant, std140) uniform PushConstant {
    uint height;
} constant;

const uint kernel[5] = uint[5](56,250,412,250,56);

void main()
{
    int height = int(constant.height);
    ivec2 coord = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x,gl_GlobalInvocationID.y);
    uvec4 outPixel = uvec4(0,0,0,255);
    uint sum=0;
    for(int dr=0;dr<5;dr++){
        int yc=coord.y+dr-2;
        if(yc<0){
            yc=0;
        }
        if(yc>=height){
            yc=height-1;
        }
        vec2 c = vec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x,yc);
        sum+=texture(inputImage,c).r*kernel[dr];
    }
    outPixel.r = sum>>10;
    imageStore(outputImage,coord,outPixel);
}
```

---

```
#version 450 core
#pragma shader_stage(compute)

layout (local_size_x_id = 0, local_size_y_id = 1) in;

layout (binding=0) uniform usampler2D inputImage;
layout (binding=1, r32i) uniform writeonly iimage2D outputImage;

void main()
{
    //TODO find a better way to get size (push constant?)
    ivec2 textureSize2d = textureSize(inputImage,0);
    int width = textureSize2d.x;
    int height = textureSize2d.y;

    ivec2 c = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    uvec4 g = texture(inputImage,c);

    ivec4 outValue = ivec4(0,0,0,0);

    if(c.x>0 && c.x<width-1 && c.y>0 && c.y<height-1){
        int nms=0;
        int mag=int(g.x);
        if (mag>0) {
            int dir=int(g.y);
            if (dir==1) {
                uvec4 g1 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y));
                uvec4 g2 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y));
                int mag_g1 = int(g1.x);
                int mag_g2 = int(g2.x);
                if (mag<mag_g1){
                    nms=0;
                }else if (mag<=mag_g2) {
                    nms=0;
                }else {
                    nms=mag;
                }
            } else if (dir==2) {
                uvec4 g1 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y-1));
                uvec4 g2 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y+1));
                int mag_g1 = int(g1.x);
                int mag_g2 = int(g2.x);
                if (mag<mag_g1){
                    nms=0;
                }else if (mag<=mag_g2) {
                    nms=0;
                }else {
                    nms=mag;
                }
            } else if (dir==3) {
                uvec4 g1 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x,c.y+1));
                uvec4 g2 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x,c.y-1));
                int mag_g1 = int(g1.x);
                int mag_g2 = int(g2.x);
                if (mag<mag_g1){
                    nms=0;
                }else if (mag<=mag_g2) {
                    nms=0;
                }else {
                    nms=mag;
                }
            } else {
                uvec4 g1 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y+1));
                uvec4 g2 = texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y-1));
                int mag_g1 = int(g1.x);
                int mag_g2 = int(g2.x);
                if (mag<mag_g1){
                    nms=0;
                }else if (mag<=mag_g2) {
                    nms=0;
                }else {
                    nms=mag;
                }
            }
        }
        outValue.x = nms;
    }
    imageStore(outputImage,c,outValue);
}
```

---

```
#version 450 core
#pragma shader_stage(compute)

layout (local_size_x_id = 0, local_size_y_id = 1) in;

layout (binding=0) uniform usampler2D inputImage;
layout (binding=1, rg8ui) uniform writeonly uimage2D outputImage;
layout (binding=2, r32f) uniform writeonly image2D outGx;
layout (binding=3, r32f) uniform writeonly image2D outGy;

//[t_l,t_h]
layout (push_constant, std140) uniform PushConstant {
    ivec2 thresh;
} constant;

void main()
{
    int gx=0;
    int gy=0;
    int magnitude = 0;
    int direction = 0;
    int t_l = constant.thresh.x;

    ivec2 c = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    //TODO find a better way to get size (push constant?)
    ivec2 textureSize2d = textureSize(inputImage,0);
    int width = textureSize2d.x;
    int height = textureSize2d.y;

    uvec4 outValue = uvec4(0,0,0,0);

    if(c.x>0 && c.x<width-1 && c.y>0 && c.y<height-1){

        gx = int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y-1)).r)+
        int(2*texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y)).r)+
        int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y+1)).r)-
        int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y-1)).r)-
        int(2*texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y)).r)-
        int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y+1)).r);

        gy = int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y-1)).r)+
        int(2*texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x,c.y-1)).r)+
        int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y-1)).r)-
        int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x-1,c.y+1)).r)-
        int(2*texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x,c.y+1)).r)-
        int(texture(inputImage,vec2(c.x+1,c.y+1)).r);

        imageStore(outGx,c,vec4(gx,0.0,0.0,0.0));
        imageStore(outGy,c,vec4(gy,0.0,0.0,0.0));

        magnitude = gx*gx+gy*gy;

        if(magnitude>=t_l*t_l){
            // Rotate by PI/8
            int xr=gx*924+gy*383;
            int yr=gy*924-gx*383;
            if (xr>=0) {
                if (yr>=0) {
                    if (xr>yr)
                    direction=4;
                    else
                    direction=3;
                } else {
                    if (xr>-yr)
                    direction=1;
                    else
                    direction=2;
                }
            } else {
                if (yr>=0) {
                    if (-xr>yr)
                    direction=1;
                    else
                    direction=2;
                } else {
                    if (-xr>-yr)
                    direction=4;
                    else
                    direction=3;
                }
            }
        }
        outValue.r = uint(magnitude);
        outValue.g = uint(direction);
    }
    imageStore(outputImage,c,outValue);
}
```

Some things i tried with no luck:

- Took any barriers and memory ranges invalidate from code
- Changed type of output arrays back to host to be COHERENT rather than CACHED
- Added new invalidate memory range on memcpy to input staging buffer that is the start of the pipeline
- Updated to Vulkan 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 based on spec of Adreno 619 (code is current 1.0)
- Tried a couple different versions of NDK (25.0.X and 24.0.X) (code is currently on 22.0.X)
- Validation layer does not highlight any issue on the code
- Added a barrier before data is copied into to input staging buffer in pipeline
- Forcing a usleep before data is copied into to input staging buffer in pipeline (in a rough attempt to simulate "a barrier")
- Tested a few different camera resolutions with 1280x720 showing the issue less frequently and 720x480 not showing the issue at all (?)

Comment: hi krOoze, not sure what you mean by the same image... all the edges from around 2/3rds of the image are clamped until the end row in the "bad case" image i posted

Comment: You are right! Somehow the links got messed up. I edited and re uploaded the images. Hopefully that sorts it out. Thanks for pointing it out krOoze!

Comment: Problem with prose is it communicates author intentions, not bugs. You should include some code. The output looks somewhat correct if we assume the source image is glitched in a way such the last line is just repeated.

Comment: Thanks krOoze, added the main code with pipelines and shaders. More and ill have to rethink how to share...

Comment: @krOoze i think it might be the push constants. in this particular device they are not working in the shader as expected. i've reduced the code to just run a simple shader (taking a push constant) that changes the values of what is returned based on that constant. it seems the push constant changes value... sometimes it's right sometimes it's not. all other devices tested behave as normal. at least i know where to focus...

Comment: Mobile devices can be a mixed bag. Looks like relatively new device. Have you tried to update the OS? I am not clear what you mean by  "Updated to Vulkan 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3". If you mean SDK, **always use the latest version** regardless, which gives the largest validation coverage. Also make sure the validation layers **actually** work (by breaking something). And don't forget to enable all the validation layer extra features, so things like synchronization and shaders are also checked.

Comment: You don't seem to be checking `VkResult`s, which can cause surprises. For example, you don't even know if by chance the Device was Lost.

Comment: Can't say more without seeing the code of all those abstractions. Is the copy out of the result also correctly synchronized?

Comment: hi @krOoze, thanks for your support and guidelines. Yes, the device has a year or so and it is up to date. Yes, i meant using different Vk SDKs which in Android mean updating NDKs so 1.2 & 1.3 become available.

Comment: I was not aware that as you use more recent SDK's the validation layers would cover more, thanks so much for that pointer. I noticed that the validation layers native libs i'm using (1.3.X) do highlight other stuff in other smartphones so you are right - that is potentially broken in this device, i will try on purpose like you say. Yes, VK checks are not being made and that is a something to be worked on soon. I will keep you up do date.

Comment: It is somewhat unfortunate it is packaged that way. If you test it on desktop, you can use the **actually** [latest Vulkan SDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home). Though they do seem to publish [Android binaries](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/releases), which apparently you are supposed to [just copy in into your NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/validation-layer#prebuilt-binaries)..

Comment: @krOoze Yes,that is what i meant by "the validation layers native libs do highlight issues in other smartphones". In Android, even if you are using 1.0 you can include the validation layer libs from later versions and still get valid warnings. Regarding the device, I think it's a Samsung issue - i've raised with them. PushConstants do not seem to work in this simple use case. It might be my pipeline because the Google RenderScript-Vulkan migration example app works ok and uses UBOs and PushConstants. For now, workaround for me is to use textureSize in the shader without any visible overhead.

Comment: @krOoze just a quick follow up on this: it ended up being an hardware issue - Samsung/Qualcomm are looking into this.